# Функция которая оборачивает в span по координатам с массива обьектов

Tags: javascript

Знатоки JS, вот пытась решить задачку, в которой есть стринг, и координаты по которым нужно вставить span.
В результате должно быть так примерно (может и индексами промахнулся):
Дофига текста, а **span** вот этот фрагмент зеленый **span** , а вот тут дальше дофига теста, **span** и еще одно зеленое **span**
Как я делаю, но не получается(

```
const str = 'Дофига текста, а вот этот фрагмент зеленый, 
а вот тут дальше дофига теста, и еще одно зеленое';
const coordinates = [
  { in: 18, out: 45 },
  { in: 77, out: 94 },
];
const arrFromString = str.split('');
let strWhithSpan = '';
let strNotspan = '';
const resString = coordinates.reduce((acc, cord) => {

  arrFromString.map((str, index) => {
    if (index+1 > cord.in && index+1 < cord.out) {
      strWhithSpan = strWhithSpan + str;
      acc = `<span>${strWhithSpan}</span>`;
    } else {
      strNotspan = strNotspan + str;
      acc = strNotspan;
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не мучайтесь выставляйте индексы поверяя предварительно.

Попробуйте так

```js
const str = 'Дофига текста, а вот этот фрагмент зеленый, а вот тут дальше дофига теста, и еще одно зеленое';
const coordinates = [
  { in: 17, out: 41 },
  { in: 75, out: 92 },
];
const arrFromString = str.split('');
const resString = arrFromString.map((strPart, index) => {  
    if (coordinates.map(cord=>cord.in).includes(index)) {
      return `<span>${strPart}`;
    } else if (coordinates.map(cord=>cord.out).includes(index)) {
      return `${strPart}</span>`;
    } else {
      return strPart;
    }  
  
}).join("");


console.log(resString);
```

сокращенный вариант

```js
const str = 'Дофига текста, а вот этот фрагмент зеленый, а вот тут дальше дофига теста, и еще одно зеленое';
const coordinates = [
  { in: 17, out: 41 },
  { in: 75, out: 92 },
];
const arrFromString = str.split('');
const resString = arrFromString.map((strPart, index) => 
    coordinates.map(cord=>cord.in).includes(index)? `<span>${strPart}`: coordinates.map(cord=>cord.out).includes(index)? `${strPart}</span>`:strPart
).join("");

console.log(resString);
```

Comment: Чего-то текст Задвоился))))

Comment: щя секундочку верну

Comment: Да исправил, спс

Comment: Спасибо. Век живи, век учись, как бы мне вот так все решать, Изначально я выбрал неправильный подход, мыслил по другому.

Comment: Не за что пользуйтесь